# Sequelize check whether time is between the times in the db

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

In my node js app, I have a situation where I have to get the **current time** and check whether it is between the **start time** and **end time** in the db table. First, I submit some data with **start time** and **end time** to the database. Then, I have a scheduler where in each minute, it checks the current time and check whether its between the **start time** and **end time** in db table to continue. I cannot figure out how to achieve this with sequelize. I couldn't find the solution with `between` condition in sequelize. It only helps if we are sending start time and end time, and date we should compare is in db as I understood. *Not the one I need.*

I have this sample code I wrote to make it understandable but it's syntactically wrong.

```
const data = dataSource.DBTableName.findAll({
  attributes: [
      // db columns
  ],
  where: {
      trackStartTime < currentTime, // This current time should be between trackStartTime and trackEndTime in db
      trackEndTime > currentTime
  }
});
```

If someone can help me how to achieve it with sequlize, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```js
const data = dataSource.DBTableName.findAll({
  attributes: [
      // db columns
  ],
  where: {
      [Op.and]: [
        {
          trackStartTime: {
            [Op.lte]: currentTime
          }  
        },
        {
          trackEndTime: {
           [Op.gte]: currentTime
          }
        }
      ]
    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the time from the database for `NOW()` and then return results from the database where that value is `BETWEEN` the `trackStartTime` and `trackEndTime` you can use `sequelize.where()` to generate the condition, `sequelize.fn()` by passing in 'NOW', and the `Op.between` operator for the arguments, passing in via `sequelize.col()` for each column.

```js
const { Op } = Sequelize; 

const data = dataSource.DBTableName.findAll({
  attributes: [ /* db columns */ ],
  where: {
    sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('NOW'), {
      [Op.between]: [
        sequelize.col('trackStartTime'), 
        sequelize.col('trackEndTime')
      ],
    }),
  },
});
```

```sql
SELECT ? FROM `DBTableName` 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN `trackStartTime` AND `trackEndTime`
```